# Create D3 x-axis that excludes weekends and holidays

Tags: d3.js, graph, linechart, nvd3.js

I am trying to create a simple d3 chart using the library NVD3 (the information that I am using NVD3 is somewhat irrelevant), and I am struggling to create the correct x-Axis and get the correct spacing between points.  I do want a scaled display of dates, so, the jump from 2014-03-01 to 2014-04-01 would be less than to 2014-03-07.  So essentially what I want is the typical default time scale, except I don't want it to consider weekends and holidays as possible points, because the market is closed on these days.

I apologize in advance that I cannot post code, as the data is from a source I can't put into a fiddle or bin.

Essentially the data that I am returned is not garunteed to have the price of a stock on a valid date, and some points could be missing.  Currently a single day tick on the x-axis is twice as large as the regular single day tick should be if there is data on a Monday and a Friday.

If this is confusing please tell me and I will try and reword.

If anyone has done this before or has any insight, all help is appreciated!

Comment: It sounds like you would need a custom scale or a combination of existing scales for this. You certainly can't tell the time scale to ignore certain days.

Comment: Yes I think you are right, my question on that would be how does one go about creating a custom scale?

Comment: A simple approach would be to use an ordinal scale and enumerate all "allowed" dates.

Comment: So what I finally ended up doing was just scrapping the whole idea of using dates as the X-axis, at least for the data input.  So now I am just using numbers from 0-(length of data array) and I have a matching array of dates where the number for X is the index of the date in the date array.  This works for me because I really only need the graph to appear to be showing showing the data for that date, the input data itself does not not actually need to be a date array.  So basically the xAxis tick format converts these indexes to the corresponding date in my cached date array

Comment: @bmeyers Can you show me the solution you have?

Comment: @Dev unfortunately, I do not have access to that source code any longer

Comment: @bmeyers small hints:)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [D3 Non-Continuous Dates Domain Gives Gaps on X-Axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28129412/d3-non-continuous-dates-domain-gives-gaps-on-x-axis)